# Kendo ui Column Chart Labels

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

With the Kendo UI column chart, is there a possible way to show a series default label with a value of 0? The labels work for pie charts and line charts.

Here is my javascript and I don't see any configuration options

http://jsfiddle.net/8YnKv/30/

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a hack solution, but if you are not concerned about decimal values, you could always set your 0 value values to something like .00001 and then use the kendo.format to round it to the nearest whole number, which is 0. Example jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8YnKv/31/

Now, if you need to preserve decimal values, then this solution will not work for you. I hope that Telerik comes up with a solution soon.